# Built a Custom html page with FB Login. I want to redirect them to Main page after using facebook login button

Tags: facebook, redirect, authentication

I built a custom page, more like a landing page with facebook login with permission. What I want is to simply redirect users to home page. My main page is www.ngncareers.com/index.php 
I built this www.ngncareers.com/index.html as landing page with facebook login. 
Please how do I redirect users to www.ngncareers.com/index.php after logging into my facebook app via www.ngncareers.com/index.html.

HERE IS MY SOURCE CODE. PLEASE CAN SOMEONE GOOD OUT THERE KINDLY ASSIST ME. I AM JUST A NOVICE ON PHP.

```
<div id="content">

    <div class="post">
    <h2>Please Login with Facebook</h2>
        <center><div class="fb-login-button" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" data-scope="email,publish_actions,manage_pages,manage_notifications,user_likes" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div></center> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
```

`window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '78797XXXXXXXXXX',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });

      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

`

Answer (score 0):

The first strange fact is that you get an index.html and index.php
you can simply have one index.php with html inside.

You can have Pop-in window's style for login into facebook.
If you use Javascript, use window.location for a proper redirection.

You should look about "button login Facebook tutorial" which would be really simple.
Look also about Facebook developers webpage for more informations and tutorials.

Hope it could help !

Comment: Well I wasn't the one that created the script. I was thinking it would be easy since am a novice in PHP. You suggestion is more complicated. thanks though

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button

On this link you can set your button and "Get the code"
You can't get easier.

Comment: How can I use this attribute "onlogin" function to my advantage in solving this. They said this is A JavaScript function to trigger when the login process is complete. can this do the redirect. And how can it be done. Can a guru here please help me out?